# Using a table for variable name in a table is not found when called for

Tags: variables, lua, lua-table

I am making quite the complex thing and I am trying to use tables as variable names cause I have found that lua works with it, that is:

```
lua
{[{1,2}]="Meep"}
```

The issue is it is callable, when I do it and try to call it using the same kind of table, it won't find it.

I have tried looking for it and such but I have no clue why it won't do this.

```
ua
local c = {[{1,2}]="Meep"}
print(c[{1,2}],c)
```

Do I expect to become but it does not.

```
"Meep",{[{1,2}]="Meep"}
```

but what I get is

```
nil,{[{1,2}]="Meep"}
```

If I however try

```
lua
local m={1,2}
local c = {[m]="Meep"}
print(c[m],c)
```

it becomes the correct one, is there a way to avoid that middle man? After all `m=={1,2}` will return true.

Comment: `m=={1,2}` is always false.  Two tables `{1,2}` and `{1,2}` are not equal to each other.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff So I have noticed, why is that so? Is there a way to circumvent it natively or do I have to do some shenanigans?

Comment: As soon as you write '{' - you're creating new table, so comparing that instance with any other will result in false.

Comment: @Vlad and there is no way to circumvent?

Comment: Most simple way to "circumvent" is to serialize: convert table `{1, 2}` to a **string** `"1;2"` and use that string as a table key.

Comment: Well that is a can of worms, thank you for that information anyway!

Comment: The other way is to use nested tables: `c[1][2][3]` instead of `c[{1,2,3}]`

Comment: The torch framework does do that kind of shenanigans. Perhaps you can use it in your project even if you don't need its other features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that **tables in lua are represented as references**. If you compare two different talbes you are comparing those references. So the equation only gets `true` if the given tables are exactly the same.

```
t = { 1, 2, 3 }
t2 = { 1, 2, 3 }
print(t == t) -- true
print(t2 == t) -- false
print(t2 == t2) -- true
```

Because of this fact, you can pass them in function per reference.

```
function f(t)
    t[1] = 5
end

t2 = { 1 }
f(t2)
print(t2[1]) -- 5
```

To bypass this behavior, you could (like suggested in comments) serialize the table before using it as a key.